# how to Delete Duplicate Rows but keeping 1 based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called scheduler. It contains following columns:

```
ID
sequence_id
schedule_time (timestamp)
processed
source_order
```

I need to delete duplicate rows from the table but keeping 1 row which has same schedule_time and source_order for a particular sequence_id where processed=0

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: A very simple solution would be to 

`delete from table where ID not in (select ID's of distinct records )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE yourTable FROM yourTable LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT MIN(ID) AS minID FROM yourTable WHERE processed = 0 GROUP BY schedule_time, source_order
) AS keepRowTable ON yourTable.ID = keepRowTable.minID
WHERE keepRowTable.ID IS NULL AND processed = 0
```

I apply from this post ;P [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)
Have you seen it?

--fixed version--

```
DELETE yourTable FROM yourTable LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT MIN(ID) AS minID FROM yourTable WHERE processed = 0 GROUP BY schedule_time, source_order
) AS keepRowTable ON yourTable.ID = keepRowTable.minID
WHERE keepRowTable.minID IS NULL AND processed = 0
```

Comment: thanks, but a slight mistake keepRowTable.minID instead of keepRowTable.ID

Comment: Thank you for your correction. Sorry for my mistake. I have fixed it as your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For mysql

```
DELETE a from  tbl a , tbl b WHERE a.Id>b.Id and
a.sequence_id= b.sequence_id and a.processed=0;
```

Comment: the query is taking lots of time to execute. i have 3000 rows

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql

Comment: its taking too long to execute.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to remove duplicates - is definitely to force them out by adding an index, leaving only one copy of each left in the table:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE dates ADD PRIMARY KEY (

  ID
  sequence_id
  schedule_time
  processed
  source_order
)
```

Now if you have a key, you might need to delete it and so on, but the point is that when you add a unique key with IGNORE to a table with duplicates - the bahavior is to delete all the extra records / duplicates. So after you added this key, you now just need to delete it again to be able to make new duplicates :-)

Now if you need to do more complex filtering (on witch one of the duplicates to keep that you can not just include in indexes - although unlikely), you can create a table at the same time as you select and input what you want in it - all in the same query:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp SELECT ..fields..  GROUP BY ( ..what you need..)

DROP TABLE original_table

ALTER TABLE tmp RENAME TO original_table_name
```